# WiFi monitor that is iOS compatible

Tags: ios, wifi, display, airplay

I am trying to find a Display that can allow my iOS, MacBook Pro to connect to it wirelessly.

I am looking for a solution with the least number of hardware components (aside from the display).

I heard of software solutions like AirDisplay, Air Parrot, Reflection but I am seeking a hardware solution (something I can take to go for a presentation)

Answer (score 1):

AppleTV is compatible with iPad 2 (and newer), and with computers since 2011

More info at: http://support.apple.com/kb/ht5404

You can hook up your AppleTV to any HDMI-compatible TV

Comment: Ultimately I want to hook it up in my car with a WiFi display. The AppleTV (by itself) doesn't create a WiFi network. I'd need a WiFi router too.

Is there a WiFi monitor that doesn't need a router, and AppleTV. Kind of like the AirPlay speakers

Comment: That's what the future Apple TV set should do, but I assume it will be a bit larger than what would be comfortable in a car... My competence is essentially with Apple products, so I cannot actually suggest a different course of action. Just a question, though: wouldn't the iPad be large enough for all passengers to see??

Comment: The MacBook Pro and any iOS device with cellular can create ad hoc wireless networks. The AppleTV could connect to the wireless network created by the device and then use AirPlay.

Comment: the iPad is a great device but I am having trouble finding a suitable car mount. Plus if I pursued this then the iPad would be configured with my Apple ID(thus my iMessages would be delivered here). So if another driver wanted to use it, they would gain access to my messages, emails. A WiFi Display would allow anyone to use their own device without worrying about giving away sensitive info. (Plus a WiFi Display would be great for presentations)

Comment: I see, I wish I could've given you a better option! Good luck with your search :)

Answer (score -1):

try this app its great for multi display and Screen sharing with Macbook or a PC
but only available for iPad, you can control ur MAC or PC too-
https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/parallels-access/id655527928?mt=8

Comment: I am seeking a hardware solution. Not a software solution.